# how to pass a dictionary object as parameter for a function in python

Tags: python, dictionary, parameters

i want to pass a dictionary object as parameter to a function. i read some post, the people recommend to use **kwargs as parameter, but when i use this keyword, it make a new dictionary instead of passing my dictionary to the function.

can you help me with a solution to pass my entire dictionary object as variable. this is a sample code that i tried to use it

```
my_dic={test:list1[],
        train:list2[]}

def prt(**kwargs):
    for txt in kwargs[test]:
        print(txt)

prt(my_dic)
```

thank you

Comment: what is wrong when simply pass your object?

Comment: Just use a normal parameter, no **

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your sample code fails well before the function is called, because your first statement has four undefined identifiers, and the values aren't properly formed.

Comment: i think my question privilege ban, because of this question. how can i remove it or fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a dictionary as parameter same way the other types of variables:

```
def prt(test):
    #If you call prt with a dictionary as parameter, test will be a dictionary
```

At difference with other kind of variables, if you modify a dictionary inside the function it will be remain modified outside.

Answer (score 1):

The function `def prt(**kwargs)` allows you to pass any number of keywords arguments you want (i.e. arguments with format "name=value"). Here is how you can define and call it:

```
def prt1(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs['test'])

prt1(test = ['A', 'B', 'C' ,'D'], train = [1, 2, 3, 4])
# ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

You can obviously use the function `def prt(aDict)`: it allows you to pass a single object (here, a dictionary) as argument. Here is how you can define and call it:

```
my_dict = {'test' : ['A', 'B', 'C' ,'D'],
           'train': [1, 2, 3, 4]

def prt2(aDict):
    print(aDict['test'])

prt2(my_dict)
# ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Answer (score 0):

`dict` is a built-in type; there's no extra "magic" for passing a dict as a functional argument.  Try this:

```
def prt(param):
    for txt in param["test"]:
        print(txt)

my_dic={"test" :[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19],
        "train":[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]}

prt(my_dic)
```

Output:

```
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
```